# Unexpected token '??' in tracer.js (in my react app)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, syntax-error

I created a new react project (said yes to all the prompts). I haven't made any changes at all, but when I try to run it, I get this error: `project-path/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:92`
`const spanName = options.spanName ?? type;`
`^`

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

there are many such double-question-marks in the file. Attached here:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
0 && (module.exports = {
    getTracer: null,
    SpanStatusCode: null,
    SpanKind: null
});
function _export(target, all) {
    for(var name in all)Object.defineProperty(target, name, {
        enumerable: true,
        get: all[name]
    });
}
_export(exports, {
    getTracer: function() {
        return getTracer;
    },
    SpanStatusCode: function() {
        return SpanStatusCode;
    },
    SpanKind: function() {
        return SpanKind;
    }
});
const _constants = require("./constants");
let api;
// we want to allow users to use their own version of @opentelemetry/api if they
// want to, so we try to require it first, and if it fails we fall back to the
// version that is bundled with Next.js
// this is because @opentelemetry/api has to be synced with the version of
// @opentelemetry/tracing that is used, and we don't want to force users to use
// the version that is bundled with Next.js.
// the API is ~stable, so this should be fine
if (process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME === "edge") {
    api = require("@opentelemetry/api");
} else {
    try {
        api = require("@opentelemetry/api");
    } catch (err) {
        api = require("next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api");
    }
}
const { context , trace , SpanStatusCode , SpanKind  } = api;
const isPromise = (p)=>{
    return p !== null && typeof p === "object" && typeof p.then === "function";
};
const closeSpanWithError = (span, error)=>{
    if (error) {
        span.recordException(error);
    }
    span.setStatus({
        code: SpanStatusCode.ERROR,
        message: error == null ? void 0 : error.message
    });
    span.end();
};
/** we use this map to propagate attributes from nested spans to the top span */ const rootSpanAttributesStore = new Map();
const rootSpanIdKey = api.createContextKey("next.rootSpanId");
let lastSpanId = 0;
const getSpanId = ()=>lastSpanId++;
class NextTracerImpl {
    /**
   * Returns an instance to the trace with configured name.
   * Since wrap / trace can be defined in any place prior to actual trace subscriber initialization,
   * This should be lazily evaluated.
   */ getTracerInstance() {
        return trace.getTracer("next.js", "0.0.1");
    }
    getContext() {
        return context;
    }
    getActiveScopeSpan() {
        return trace.getSpan(context == null ? void 0 : context.active());
    }
    trace(...args) {
        const [type, fnOrOptions, fnOrEmpty] = args;
        // coerce options form overload
        const { fn , options  } = typeof fnOrOptions === "function" ? {
            fn: fnOrOptions,
            options: {}
        } : {
            fn: fnOrEmpty,
            options: {
                ...fnOrOptions
            }
        };
        if (!_constants.NextVanillaSpanAllowlist.includes(type) && process.env.NEXT_OTEL_VERBOSE !== "1" || options.hideSpan) {
            return fn();
        }
        const spanName = options.spanName ?? type;
        // Trying to get active scoped span to assign parent. If option specifies parent span manually, will try to use it.
        let spanContext = this.getSpanContext((options == null ? void 0 : options.parentSpan) ?? this.getActiveScopeSpan());
        let isRootSpan = false;
        if (!spanContext) {
            spanContext = api.ROOT_CONTEXT;
            isRootSpan = true;
        }
        const spanId = getSpanId();
        options.attributes = {
            "next.span_name": spanName,
            "next.span_type": type,
            ...options.attributes
        };
        return api.context.with(spanContext.setValue(rootSpanIdKey, spanId), ()=>this.getTracerInstance().startActiveSpan(spanName, options, (span)=>{
                const onCleanup = ()=>{
                    rootSpanAttributesStore.delete(spanId);
                };
                if (isRootSpan) {
                    rootSpanAttributesStore.set(spanId, new Map(Object.entries(options.attributes ?? {})));
                }
                try {
                    if (fn.length > 1) {
                        return fn(span, (err)=>closeSpanWithError(span, err));
                    }
                    const result = fn(span);
                    if (isPromise(result)) {
                        result.then(()=>span.end(), (err)=>closeSpanWithError(span, err)).finally(onCleanup);
                    } else {
                        span.end();
                        onCleanup();
                    }
                    return result;
                } catch (err) {
                    closeSpanWithError(span, err);
                    onCleanup();
                    throw err;
                }
            }));
    }
    wrap(...args) {
        const tracer = this;
        const [name, options, fn] = args.length === 3 ? args : [
            args[0],
            {},
            args[1]
        ];
        if (!_constants.NextVanillaSpanAllowlist.includes(name) && process.env.NEXT_OTEL_VERBOSE !== "1") {
            return fn;
        }
        return function() {
            let optionsObj = options;
            if (typeof optionsObj === "function" && typeof fn === "function") {
                optionsObj = optionsObj.apply(this, arguments);
            }
            const lastArgId = arguments.length - 1;
            const cb = arguments[lastArgId];
            if (typeof cb === "function") {
                const scopeBoundCb = tracer.getContext().bind(context.active(), cb);
                return tracer.trace(name, optionsObj, (_span, done)=>{
                    arguments[lastArgId] = function(err) {
                        done == null ? void 0 : done(err);
                        return scopeBoundCb.apply(this, arguments);
                    };
                    return fn.apply(this, arguments);
                });
            } else {
                return tracer.trace(name, optionsObj, ()=>fn.apply(this, arguments));
            }
        };
    }
    startSpan(...args) {
        const [type, options] = args;
        const spanContext = this.getSpanContext((options == null ? void 0 : options.parentSpan) ?? this.getActiveScopeSpan());
        return this.getTracerInstance().startSpan(type, options, spanContext);
    }
    getSpanContext(parentSpan) {
        const spanContext = parentSpan ? trace.setSpan(context.active(), parentSpan) : undefined;
        return spanContext;
    }
    getRootSpanAttributes() {
        const spanId = context.active().getValue(rootSpanIdKey);
        return rootSpanAttributesStore.get(spanId);
    }
}
const getTracer = (()=>{
    const tracer = new NextTracerImpl();
    return ()=>tracer;
})();

//# sourceMappingURL=tracer.js.map
```

I wanted to replace the first '??' but i wasn't sure what to replace it with. Why is the problem here, and what can i do to fix it?

Comment: I also experienced this issue recently. Making sure that all packages I had installed were compatible solved the issue for me, as I believe some older versions did not support the **nullish coalescing operator** (??)

Comment: Why so many js tags? Please, reduce to most approiate ones.

Comment: You should list the **versions** of software you are using.  e.g.  result of `node --version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by updating node. I was on version 12, which doesn't support that syntax (check node.green for version support details).